# Toggle password field jetpack compose

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

Hi I am trying to change visualTransformation dynamically when the user click on see password button. I can manage to filter password but couldn't achive to show in plain text. Any idea for that ? Here is what I got so far.

```
fun UserInputText(
    keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    onTextChanged: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    textFieldValue: TextFieldValue,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    borderColor: Color = editTextBorderColor,
    keyboardShown: Boolean,
    onTextFieldFocused: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    focusState: Boolean,
    placeholder: String = "",
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.border(
            width = 2.dp,
            color = borderColor,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
        )
    ) {
        var lastFocusState by remember { mutableStateOf(FocusState.Inactive) }
        val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
        val focusRequesterModifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)

        BasicTextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = { onTextChanged(it) },
            modifier =
            modifier.focus().then(focusRequesterModifier)
                .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                .focusObserver { state ->
                    if (lastFocusState != state) {
                        onTextFieldFocused(state == FocusState.Active)
                    }
                    lastFocusState = state
                },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = keyboardType,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Send
            ),
            visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
            maxLines = 1,
            cursorColor = inputTextColor,
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(color = inputTextColor)
        )
        if(keyboardType == KeyboardType.Password) {
            Image(
                vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icons_watch_count_24), modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                    .padding(end = 16.dp, top = 16.dp).clickable(onClick = {})
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Check this:

```
    var passwordVisibility: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    TextField(value = "Enter Password",
        visualTransformation = if (passwordVisibility) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        leadingIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                passwordVisibility = !passwordVisibility
            }) {
                Icon(imageVector = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icons_watch_count_24))
            }
        },
        onValueChange = { })
```

Answer (score 186):

You can use the standard `TextField` composable:

```
var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
var passwordVisible by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

TextField(
    value = password,
    onValueChange = { password = it },
    label = { Text("Password") },
    singleLine = true,
    placeholder = { Text("Password") },
    visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
    trailingIcon = {
        val image = if (passwordVisible)
            Icons.Filled.Visibility
        else Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff

        // Please provide localized description for accessibility services
        val description = if (passwordVisible) "Hide password" else "Show password"

        IconButton(onClick = {passwordVisible = !passwordVisible}){
            Icon(imageVector  = image, description)
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Note: to use `Icons.Filled.Visibility` and `Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff` add in the dependencies: `implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"`

Comment: Using empty strings for content descriptions is a bad habit, it's better to set it as null to indicate that it's purely decorative or provide an actual string in your example so people understand why that it is there. I'm not sure how a screen reader would operate with a Compose TextField using PasswordVisualTransform, but I wouldn't count on this contentDescription being unneccessary.

Comment: @omiwrench It is just an example. In any case since the answer shows how to implement a password field it is correct the approach to manage also the description. Answer updated. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**Hide/Show password in jetpack compose**

```
 @Composable
    fun CommonTextFieldPassword(
        text: MutableState<String>,
        placeholder: String,
        trailingIcon: Int = R.drawable.eye,
        visibility: MutableState<Boolean> = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = text.value,
            onValueChange = { text.value = it },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                focusedLabelColor = fadedTextColor,
                textColor = headingColor,
                unfocusedLabelColor = fadedTextColor,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = fadedTextColor,
                focusedIndicatorColor = headingColor
            ),
            label = { Text(text = placeholder) },
            trailingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = trailingIcon),
                    contentDescription = "",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(25.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            visibility.value = !visibility.value
                        },
                    tint = if (visibility.value) titleColor else fadedTextColor
                )
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            visualTransformation = if (visibility.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation()
        )
    }
```